# Problems when creating methods in my task

Tags: java, class, methods

The goal is to produce this:

[Picture of the task summary here](http://gyazo.com/435892dc0bd7f471df89e10a1e009e37)

These are the errors I get when I try to compile:
[screen shot](http://gyazo.com/7aaae0a94c54c0d45d0592e5a5122964)

I have changed and fixed most of the more obvious errors I think which was mainly just stupid of me. Sorry.

I have this code

```
public class Ex5Program {

public void start() {
    Tutor[] tutors = createTutorsArray();
    printTutors(tutors);
    printOnLeaveList(tutors);
    updateTutorDetails(tutors[1]);
    printNewTutorDetails(tutors[1]);
    Tutor tutorWithMostPapers = getTutorWithMostPapers(tutors);
    printTutorWithMostPapers(tutorWithMostPapers);
}

private Tutor[] createTutorsArray() {
    String[] noPapers = {};
    String[] introductoryPapers = {"CompSci101", "CompSci111"};
    String[] coreStage1Papers = {"CompSci101", "CompSci105"};
    String[] allStageOnePapers = {"CompSci111", "CompSci101", "CompSci105"};
    String[] stageTwoPapers = {"CompSci210", "CompSci220", "CompSci225", "CompSci230"};
    Tutor[] tutors = new Tutor[7];
    tutors[5] = new Tutor("Sad Sack", 86302, introductoryPapers, false);
    tutors[4] = new Tutor("Crystal Ball", 49123, introductoryPapers, false);
    tutors[2] = new Tutor("Earl Lee Riser", 40879, allStageOnePapers, true);
    tutors[3] = new Tutor("Tom Katt", 50876, stageTwoPapers, false);
    tutors[1] = new Tutor("Candy Kane", 30869, noPapers, false);
    tutors[0] = new Tutor("Carrie Oakey", 30987, coreStage1Papers, true);
    tutors[6] = new Tutor("Sonny Day", 49586, stageTwoPapers, true);
    return tutors;
}

private void printTutors(Tutor[] tutors) {
    System.out.println("Current Tutors");
    System.out.println("==============");
    for (int i = 0; i < tutors.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + 1 + ". ");
        System.out.println(tutors[i].toString());
    }
}

private void printOnLeaveList(Tutor[] tutors) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Tutors Currently on Leave");
    System.out.println("=========================");
    for (int i = 0; i < tutors.length; i++) {
        if (tutors[i].isOnLeave()) {
            System.out.println(tutors[i].getName());
        }
    }
}


private void updateTutorDetails(Tutor tutor) {
    tutor.setName("Ali Katt");
    tutor.setStaffId(23456);
    String[] stage1Papers = {"CompSci101", "CompSci105", "CompSci111"};
    tutor.setPapers(stage1Papers);
    tutor.setOnLeave(true);
}

private void printNewTutorDetails(Tutor tutor) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Updated details");
    System.out.println("===============");
    System.out.println("Name: " + tutor.getName());
    System.out.println("Id: " + tutor.getStaffId());
    String[] papers = tutor.getPapers();
    System.out.print("Papers: ");
    if (papers.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < papers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(papers[i] + " ");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print("None");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if (tutor.isOnLeave()) {
        System.out.println("Currently on leave");
    }
}

private Tutor getTutorWithMostPapers(Tutor[] tutors) {
    Tutor tutorWithMostPapersSoFar = tutors[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < tutors.length; i++) {
        if (tutors[i].teachesMorePapersThan(tutorWithMostPapersSoFar)) {
            tutorWithMostPapersSoFar = tutors[i];
        }
    }
    return tutorWithMostPapersSoFar;
}

private void printTutorWithMostPapers(Tutor tutorWithMostPapers) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Most papers");
    System.out.println("===========");
    System.out.println(tutorWithMostPapers.getName() + " teaches more papers than any other tutor.");
}

}
```

and I created this code here(It has been changed):

```
public class Tutor {

// instance variables

private String name;
private int staffId;
private String[] papers;
private boolean onLeave;

public Tutor(String name, int staffId, String[] papers, boolean onLeave) {
    // Complete this constructor method
    this.name = name;
    this.staffId = staffId;
    this.papers = papers;
    this.onLeave = onLeave;
}
// Insert getName() method here
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
// Insert setName() method here
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
// Insert getStaffId() method here
public int getStaff(){
    return staffId;
}
// Insert setStaffId() method here
public void setStaffId(int StaffId){
    this.staffId = staffId;
}
// Insert getPapers() method here;
public  String[] getPapers(){
    return papers;
}
// Insert setPapers() method here
public void setPapers(String[] papers){
    this.papers = papers;
}
// Insert isOnLeave() method here
public boolean isOnLeave(){
    return onLeave;
}
// Insert setOnLeave() method here
public void setOnLeave(boolean OnLeave){
    this.onLeave = onLeave;
}
// Insert toString() method here
public String toString(){
    return name + "(Staff id:"+staffId+")";
}
// Insert teachesMorePapersThan() method here
public Tutor teachesMorePapersThan(Tutor other){
    return(papers.length>other.papers.length);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: What do you think a line like `tutor.setPapers(stage1Papers);` does? When you understand that, you will have solved your problem.

Comment: In your error message printscreen, there is one error that says: "getstaffId()", but in your code it's always "getStaffId()" with capital S, which is correct. So you shouldn't be getting this error...

So what errors are actually happening, and how is your code now ?

Comment: now you have one problem on public void 
`setOnLeave(boolean OnLeave){
    this.onLeave = onLeave;
}` it's the same as this.onLeave = this.onLeave; because argument variable is OnLeave and not onLeave

Answer (score 5):

Typo: `toString()` not `tostring()`, which results in `Object.toString()` is being invoked and the intended formatted string is not being returned. Change to:

```
@Override public String toString()
```

Using the `@Override` annotation would have produced a compiler error in the case of `tostring()` being the method name and alerted you to the error, because no method of that name exists in a superclass.

Several of the setter methods have missing parameters:

```
// Insert setPapers() method here
public void setPapers(){
    this.papers = papers;
}

// Insert setOnLeave() method here
public void setOnLeave(){
    this.OnLeave = OnLeave;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First error: setStaffID()

You are calling it using an int, but on your method you say it doesn't have any parameter.

Take a look that you have some others errors caused by the same mistake. Correct them first...

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the error text to find the problems.  While a newbie may instinctively just dismiss the error messages as uselesss (as a result of years of clicking the x or cancel or whatever on windows dialogues), The error text is actually the most useful resource for figuring out what the error is, 90% of the time.

For instance, the first error reads

```
File: F:\course related stuff\101\Lab06\Ex5\Ex5Program.java [line: 54]
Error: method setStaffId in class Tutor cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

If you read it carefully, you can see it tells you the **name of the file**, the **line number**, the **method call name**, the **class name containing the method**, and some additional information about the **exact type of error**.  It is even telling you what you did wrong in calling the method, by putting an "int" where "no arguments" were required, that the "actual and formal argument lists differ in length".

Read the other error messages, and you will see that they actually tell you what the problem is.

This code also needs newlines inserted to group blocks of stuff, comments added to explain exactly how it works, and a few java style violations fixed - some teachers grade for style and clarity as well as just functionality.

Also, if the reason you are failing your class is because you don't understand how to program, it may be because of excessive use of stack overflow to solve the problems.  In the real world, if you can just use somebody else's code, that's great, but the point of a programming class is is to teach you how to come up with your own code, not how to use somebody else's.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not easy to help, because i think you don't know what you are doing. But first thing when you create a set method like this:

```
public void setPapers(){
    this.papers = papers;
}
```

you should declare the arguments like this:

```
public void setPapers(String[] papers){
    this.papers = papers;
}
```

and you should know that variables names is caseSensitive so :

```
private boolean onLeave;

public boolean isOnLeave(){
    //return OnLeave; this variable is not declared 
    return onLeave;
}
```

I think you need to study a little more, because you can't read the compilation errors.